# linking multiple node types to each other

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have 2 node types, complaints and solutions.
Every node type has multiple fields.

How can I link multiple solutions to a complaint?
And the other way around, how can I link a solution to multiple complaints?

-Complaint1 -> Solution1, Solution2, Solution3

-Solution 1 is linked to Complaint1, Complaint2, Complaint3

With entity reference I can only link one on one relations.
The relations module seemed promising, but it seems it's only for admin users.

Comment: Could you add more details or your fields you have in your content types? I'm thinking you could use a taxonomy term field called parent complaint or something like that.....

Comment: The complaint has 12 fields. The solution wil we a bit shorter but wil also have 4 fields + a user wil also be linked to a solution.

Comment: Just found out that with taxonomy you can add fields, didn't know that until now. So that could be a solution.
Only problem is user can create a new taxonomy term in the taxonomy tagging field. But then it just creates a new taxonomy term with just the title filled in.

Is there a way to force users to fil in all the fields of the taxonomy they just created?

Comment: Your using drupal 7, right?

Comment: Yep i use drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I haven't test this out, but I think this should work:

1. You first need  a way to generate a taxonomy term for each Complaint node. I think that the [NAT](https://www.drupal.org/project/nat) could help with that or through [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
2. Next, add a term reference field for Solutions, enable multiple selections but disable the ability to create terms.
3. Override the term reference view for that particular vocabulary through a custom url using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto), this would be the "Complaint1 -> Solution1, Solution2, Solution3" part
4. For "Solution 1 is linked to Complaint1, Complaint2, Complaint3", you already have links to the taxonomy term simply by displaying the field in your node. You could also do this through views.

Done! Hope it works!